# Inserting time in mysql database

Tags: mysql, time

Actually I have time and exp field in mysql database.

I am successfully inserting current time in time field using : CURTIME();
But i also want to insert exp time in exp filed ie: current time + 2 hrs..
It should show :
time : 4:00:12AM
exp : 6:00:12AM

Answer (score 0):

You could use [addtime()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) for this. 
So for your example:

```
SELECT ADDTIME(curtime()', '02:00:00.0000')
```

should work.

Comment: Alternatively he can use `INTERVAL 2 HOURS` as the second parameter, which is a bit more understandable than `02:00:00.0000`

Answer (score 0):

Use following format:

```
INSERT INTO table1
(field1, field2,....,cur_time_field,exp_field,...fieldN)
VALUES
(value1,value2,....,NOW(),DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR),...fieldN)
```

**Update:**

```
INSERT INTO table1
(field1, field2,....,cur_time_field,exp_field,...fieldN)
VALUES
(value1,value2,....,NOW(),DATE_ADD(CURTIME(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR),...fieldN)
```

Comment: DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR) return NULL

Comment: @user3133175 - select DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR) ads 2 hours on now(). I have verified the result MYSQL 5.6.17 and believe that it should behave in other versions as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
SELECT ADDTIME(CURTIME(),'02:00:00.000000');
```

Hope This Will Help You.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATE_ADD` function to specify the interval which is 2 hours in your case. `DATE_ADD(CUR_TIME, INTERVAL 2 HOUR)` will work fine.

Here is the great documentation for date time functions -

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add